# Javascript regexp check input contains only zeros

Tags: javascript, regex

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

I check input to match digits and letters but, how I should check if input contains only zeros?

ex:

```
'01weye0y4' = true;
'00' = false;
```

Comment: What if the user inputs only `11111` or `22222` etc. Is it valid?

Comment: So just use number `Number(str)===0`

Comment: What's wrong with `/^0+$/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier, as @epascarello said, just to check whether or not the entered value's Number form equal to 0 (with `+val === 0` or something similar). But if you need to use pattern, here's one possible approach:

```
var p = /^(?!0+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
p.test('00'); // false
p.test('001001weye0y4'); // true
```

The key is using negative lookahead checking whether or not the string contains zeros only.

---

This can be easily expanded to check for any digit:

```
var p = /^(?!([0-9])\1*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
```

This pattern fails if the value uses only a single digit (so both '0', '00', '1', and '11' don't pass the check).